# How do I refer to this JSON Object Data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi

I want to reference my `Strapi` database to my Next.JS Frontend. How can I reference a JSON data if it is also an object within the object?

As an example, to access the name, I use `{activity.name}`. How can I access the `providerName`?

I tried `{activity.provider.providerName}` but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bowling in Mundsburg",
    "activityType": "Bowling",
    "profileType": "Basic",
    "adventureType": "Activity",
    "slug": "bowling-in-new-york",
    "provider": {
      "id": 1,
      "providerName": "Bowlingcenter New York",
      "slug": "bowlingcenter-new-york",
      "published_at": "2021-09-26T12:06:12.670Z",
      "created_at": "2021-09-26T12:04:28.585Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-09-26T12:06:12.690Z"
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Please provide us with the error!

Answer (score 1):

could you try like so?

```
const strapiRes = [
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bowling in Mundsburg",
    "activityType": "Bowling",
    "profileType": "Basic",
    "adventureType": "Activity",
    "slug": "bowling-in-new-york",
    "provider": {
      "id": 1,
      "providerName": "Bowlingcenter New York",
      "slug": "bowlingcenter-new-york",
      "published_at": "2021-09-26T12:06:12.670Z",
      "created_at": "2021-09-26T12:04:28.585Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-09-26T12:06:12.690Z"
    }
  }
];
const whatYouAreAskingFor = strapiRes[0].provider.providerName
```

also if you are looping try something like:

```
strapiRes.map(activity => activity.provider.providerName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This would only work if I have the JSON within my code, but I am fetching my data from the STRAPI API. Therefore I want to access the proivderName, but I am not getting it.